# Creating a dropdownlist c# mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am implementing a backoffice in mvc3 c# and i would like to have a field that is a drop down list with 3 fields "ComingSoon,Out,Showing". These fields are not a part of any class. Do i have to create a helper class ? 
i have tried the following

```
<% List<string> foo = new List<string>();
   foo.Add("Showing");
   foo.Add("ComingSoon);"
   foo.Add("Out");

   Html.DropDownList(foo, Model.Status); %>
```

Status is the field in the db that need to be updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Html.DropDownList("Status", 
    new SelectListItem[]{ new SelectListItem{ Text= "Showing", Value="Showing"},
    //same for others
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using model binding, I'd suggest:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.Status, 
                         new List<SelectListItem>() { 
                                new SelectListItem{ Text= "Showing", Value="Showing"},
                                new SelectListItem{ Text= "ComingSoon", Value="ComingSoon"},
                                new SelectListItem{ Text= "Out", Value="Out"}
                         }); %>
```

For modelbinding, always use the ones with 'For' at the end, it makes the Post-method easier + you get feedback if the name does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can create dropdownlist this way.

```
@{          
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> dropdownList =
                                                        new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
                dropdownList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0,"Showing"));
                dropdownList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1,"ComingSoon"));
                dropdownList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2,"Out"));
                SelectList selectList = new SelectList(dropdownList, "key", "value", 0);

}

@Html.DropDownList("foo", selectList)
```